# getting jquery to trigger onclick off a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I do apologize if this is an easy fix, I'm a tad new to jquery. To start I don't think that it is my initial call that is messing up because if I put a simple alert function in than it will work fine onclick, basically when this `<li>` is clicked on, jquery trigers an ajax to php function sending the class of the `<li>` to a php script and back, opening an alert with the result. As far as I can tell it should be working, but again my knowledge is rather limited. Any change anyone can take a look at what I have and see if you can clean it up at all, currently nothing happens onclick, no errors even appear in the console. But I imagine that even my ajax call is wrong. Any ideas why nothing happens on click?

HTML:

```
  <li title = "Previous Month"  id = "changeMonthBack" class = "<?php echo date('n'); ?>"><img src="images/leftArrow.gif" width="54" height="45" alt="previous month"></li>
```

jQuery/javascript:

```
//javascript document

$(document).ready(function(){
//need to do an onclick for getting the new month(previous)
$(".changeMonthBack").click(function(){
  function calendar(){
    //set the id for php
    var identifier = 1;
    //get the class to use for month
        var str = document.getElementById("changeMonthBack").class;
    //get the month number
    //if the month is 1, we obviously need it to be 12
    if str == 1{
        var month = 12;
    }
    else{
        var month = str - 1;
    }
      $.post("redraw.php"),{
        identifier: identifier,
        month: month
      },
        function(data,status){
          alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  };
})//end function 1
```

});

Comment: You know, there are at least 2 major syntax errors in your code. Let alone you're using an id selector when you have a class in the html.

Comment: Just noticed the selector issue. Care to tell me the syntax errors?

Comment: @JohnDoe Do yourself a favor, and open the console. That will tell you your errors.

Comment: `$.post("redraw.php"),{` you shouldn't close `)` there; `if str == 1` missing parentheses, and a 3rd one noted in Arun's answer.

Comment: @iambriansreed "Any change anyone can take a look at what I have and see if you can clean it up at all, currently nothing happens onclick, no errors even appear in the console"

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with the script.
1. As Aesthete suggested the selector should be an id selector `#changeMonthBack`
2. You are creating a closure method called `calendar` but never called it
3. There were multiple syntax error (Use a javascript editor like [spket](http://www.spket.com/))

You are creating a function called `calendar` but never calls it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // need to do an onclick for getting the new month(previous)
            $("#changeMonthBack").click(function() {
                        // set the id for php
                        var identifier = 1;
                        // get the class to use for month
                        var str = parseInt($(this).attr('class'),10);
                        // get the month number
                        // if the month is 1, we obviously need it to be 12
                        if (str == 1) {
                            var month = 12;
                        } else {
                            var month = str - 1;
                        }
                        $.post("redraw.php", {
                                    identifier : identifier,
                                    month : month
                                },

                                function(data, status) {
                                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: "
                                            + status);
                                });
                    });
        });
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("changeMonthBack").class;` doesn't look very correct. Elements have a `className` property.

Comment: That did it man thanks so much, i suppose in the future i just need to be a little more tedious with it. Also, thanks fors explaing the issue at hand

Comment: @FabrícioMatté sorry missed it, corrected with `$(this).attr('class')`

Comment: Yes I also missed it on my first read-through. Nice work rewriting it all. +1 `=]`

Comment: Sorry guys still new to jquery, any chance one of you can link to a solid tutorial?